# How to make a list of array from a user input from given numbers only

Tags: php

I have a array say ,

$box=[1,2,3,6];

What I want?
The user input $n should be equal to array_sum of the new array ,given that it should be done through the given numbers only from the array of $box.

Note: the number can be repeated.
the larger number should be taken first.

### here is the same input/op

If user enters $n= 9
a new array is created say $parcel=[6,3];

if user enter $n= 18
a new array is created say $parcel=[6,6,6];

if user enter $n= 21
a new array is created say $parcel=[6,6,6,3];

if user enter $n= 3
a new array is created say $parcel=[3];

if user enter $n= 5
a new array is created say $parcel=[3,2];

What have I tried?

```
error_reporting();
$n = 7;
$box = [6, 3, 2, 1];
$parcel = [];
if (in_array($n, $box)) {
    $j = array_search($n, $box);
    array_push($parcel, $box[$j]);

} else {

    function myfunction($num)
    {
        foreach ($GLOBALS['box'] as $bob) {
            if (array_sum($GLOBALS['parcel']) !== $GLOBALS['n']) {
                return array_push($GLOBALS['parcel'], $bob);
            }

        }

    }

    array_map("myfunction", $box);

}
print_r($parcel);
//print_r($new);
```

Comment: 6 + 1 = 7 why is that the output for 9?

Comment: Have you made any effort yourself so far?  Also why spam the language tags?

Comment: @Peilonrayz sorry i have edited it,

Comment: @NigelRen i have edited and pasted my code, iam new here apologies for that, i can understand  php,c++ or py - just wanted the logic, i dont know why people are down voting this , its not a spam question at all.

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment to me. That being said what you need to do is go back over your requirements and figure out an algorithm that goes through box,  subtracts the box value from the inputted value and determines if the number is positive, zero or negative.  If the resulting number is positive, then push it to parcel and go for another cycle, if it is negative go to the next item in the box and repeat the subtract, and if it is zero then push that number as the final in the parcel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php 
        function SplitPackages ($items, $packages = array()) {
            rsort($packages);
            $packs = array();
            foreach ($packages as $box) {
                if ($items >= $box) {
                    while ($items >= $box ) {
                        $items = $items - $box;
                        $packs[] = $box;
                    }
                }
            }
            return $packs;
        }

        $items = 90;
        $packages = [6, 3, 2, 1];   
        $packs = SplitPackages ($items, $packages);
        print_r(packs);   
        // Is this what you need?
    ?>
```

Your welcome enjoy coding!

Comment: Thank you soooo much dude, i was thinking for a long code , you made it so short , iam  extremly thank full to you mate. was searching from 2 days -thank you once again.